# Is it possible to change the view of the Site Contents page? (SharePoint Online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-contents

I have a requirement to create a list of certain document libraries so users can navigate the site. In 2007, it was possible to filter views of the Site Contents page so only Document Libraries would show up. I cannot figure out how to do this in SharePoint Online. Is this feature completely gone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to filter the Site Contents page in SharePoint Online like in MOSS 2007, however, **it is not supported to filter the Site Contents page** in SharePoint Online.

May be in future, Microsoft will provide this functionality till then as a workaround, I recommend to use Content Search web part to display all the lists or libraries on the site based on your requirements.

**Reference:**

- [Display a dynamic view of content on a page by adding the Content Query Web Part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Display-a-dynamic-view-of-content-on-a-page-by-adding-the-Content-Query-Web-Part-3e35bd58-d159-43d6-bfc7-77878b4a856d)
- [How to use SharePoint Content Search to show sites](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/sharepoint-2013-content-search-site-portal) (It's showing sites but you can configure it for only lists and libraries.)